# Top 2 Salary Grouped By Department

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the table I am referring to.

[image]

I want to find ou the 2 Employees in each department with highest salary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Further to the above answer, if there are ties (multiple employees sharing the same salary), you can use the following to bring them all through instead of just picking two at random (which is what the `ROW_NUMBER` clause will do)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Dept ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS rn
   FROM MyTable ) t
WHERE t.rn <= 2
```

Comment: Cool. This seems to be a better one and DENSE_RANK() is a new learning for me.

Comment: @Dibstar: if Dept has 2 duplicate salaries it returns 3 salaries. better go for ROW_NUMBER()

Answer (score 4):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the top salaries per Department, then select the first two records from each departmental partiton:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Dept ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS rn
   FROM MyTable ) t
WHERE t.rn <= 2
```